# Is there any way to avoid instanceof by using generics?

Tags: java, generics, polymorphism

I have a process where multiple places can generate error messages and success messages, so I would like to track them all with one class and then at end of the process, group the messages by the different 'types'.
Something along these lines:

```
public class Message {
  String message;
  public Message(String message) {
      this.message = message;
  }
}

public class ErrorMessage extends Message {};
public class FileErrorMessage extends ErrorMessage {};
public class OkMessage extends Message {};
```

and so on.  (I'm skipping constructors in derived classes for clarity). I can discriminate among the List by using the **instanceof** operator, **but** I think generics would be more elegant, but then how do I discriminate among them in a List ?

```
Message<ErrorMessage> eMsg = new Message<ErrorMessage>("invalid user");
Message<FileErrorMessage> feMsg = new Message<FileErrorMessage>("file not found");
```

I thought of using enums

```
enum MessagType { ERROR, FILE_ERROR, OK }
```

for the different classes but I could not come up with a solution.  Thanks.

Comment: Discriminate against them to do *what*? If you're looking for a totally generic solution (as in, doing a priori unknown things), you'd need to use the [Visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern). If you want to do specific, a priori known things, you can use polymorphism.

Comment: "I thought of using enums [...] in the different classes" You can use a single class with an enum field. Your `Message` could then provide methods like `MessageType getType()` and `String getMessage()`.

Comment: Well, I want to add them all to one list, so that errors defined in the future can be added to the list.  It looks like the Java Exception classes follow the pattern I described.  At the end of the process, I want to send ErrorMessages to one place, OkMessages to another, etc.

Answer (score 3):

What you can typically do in this situation is make Message have a function that can be overridden by the subclasses. Then each subclass can have its own behavior when that function is called, or it can retain the default behavior for Messages. If no default makes sense, you can make Message an abstract class.

Then you can loop through lists and do things like:

```
for (Message m : messages) {
    m.function();
}
```

Hope this is what you were looking for!

Edit: In response to your comment below, you can do something like this (with guava):

```
SetMultimap<Class, Message> messagesByType = HashMultimap.create();
for (Message m : messages) {
    messagesByType.add(m.getClass(), m);
}
```

Then you can do a nested loop through `messagesByType` to handle each different type one at a time. That being said, I don't really see the need to ever do this, given the initial response of mine, but this is to answer your question.

Comment: I want to be able to tell the difference among all the messages in one list without using instanceof.  Of course all the classes have the getMessage():String method.

Answer (score 2):

Using generics in this case makes no sense to me. Using inheritance to discriminate by the type of message woud make sense if different types of message had different behavior, but this doesn't seem to be the case.

So, I would just have the type of message as an attribute of the `Message` class:

```
enum MessageType { ERROR, FILE_ERROR, OK }

public class Message {

    private final String message;

    private final MessageType type;

    public Message(String message, MessageType type) {
        this.message = message;
        this.type = type;
    }

    public MessageType getType() {
        return this.type;
    }

    // getter for message
}
```

In general, you should keep it simple, see the [KISS principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle).

**EDIT:**

If you want to group messages by type, you can do it as follows:

```
Map<MessageType, Message> messagesByType = messages.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Message::getType));
```

`messages` is a `List` containing all the messages.

Comment: hmm...
    class ErrorMessage extends Message {
         private final MessageType type = MessageType.Error;
         ...
        ...
    }

Comment: @bretter My point is that you shouldn't be using inheritance at all

Comment: Well, I guess I'm asking for a pattern like the Exception classes without having to use instanceof to tell them apart when they're in a List<Exception>.

Comment: @bretter I think you can use the `getType()` method to discriminate.

Comment: @bretter Why do you need to discriminate? What do you need to do for one type of message that you can't do for another type of message?

Comment: At the end of the process, I want to group the various Messages by type.  Then I can send the FILE_ERROR types to one email list, the OK types to another department, etc.   Simple enough to do with the instanceof or getType(), but the only reason for getType() is to avoid instanceof.  
Spring MVC has an Exception Handler Controller where one can define a handler for different Exceptions.  handle(IOException ex); handle(RuntimeException c); etc.  One can format a response depending on the type of Exception.

Comment: @bretter Yes, you can do that with Spring, but I think it's hardly the case here. If you want to group messages by type, see my updated answer.